# "Invalid recognition 'config': bad language code." when it shouldn't be

Tags: php, json, google-speech-api

Trying to run the speech recognition in php returns an error stating that it can't recognize the language code from the external .json file. On the other hand, Google's documentation on the API clearly states that it should.

I have also used the EXACT SAME config file to run the call from the CLI with curl and it worked perfectly fine. I have no idea why this isn't working.

The .json RecognitionConfig file looks as follows:

```
"config": {
  //encoding is missing since I have an external process converting
  //the files to .wav format
  "sampleRateHertz":8000,
  "audioChannelCount": 1,
  "enableSeparateRecognitionPerChannel": false,
  "languageCode":"ro-RO",
  "maxAlternatives": 1,
  "profanityFilter": false,
  "speechContexts": [
    {
      "phrases": [
        "lorem",
        "ipsum",
        "dolor",
        "sit amet"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "enableWordTimeOffsets": false,
  "model": "default",
  "useEnhanced": false
  }
```

Despite "ro-RO" being a language code that's recognized in the official documentation, loading the page returns an error saying
"Invalid recognition 'config': bad language code.", "code": 3, "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "details": [], 
What gives? Where did I go wrong and more importantly WHY?

The php code calling and consturcting is as follows:

```
$recogConfig = '/path/to/config/file.json';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json');
//both use absolute paths

$configString = file_get_contents($recogConfig);
$configObj = json_decode($configString/*, true -this doesn't work either*/);
echo $configString; //works, returns the contents aforementioned json file
```

After which, any type of interaction with $cofigObj gives a "Call on null" error. I understand I've fumbled the passing of the JSON file into php, but every guide I've studied says this should work, and I can't figure out which part of it crashes. Moreso than a simple answer, I would like to know how to make the passing of the json file more verbose, so I can see where the process crashes and why.

Comment: The contents of the JSON file are not proper JSON, the element "config" needs to be wrapped in curly brackets. So it should start with `{ "config": { ... } }`.

Comment: Fixed that, the script returns "Call to undefined method stdClass::setLanguageCode()" when trying to run $configObj -> setLanguageCode();

Commenting that instruction returns "Uncaught Exception: Expect Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\RecognitionConfig" , 

while trying to build ```$config = (new RecognitionConfig($configObj));```
returns "InvalidArgumentException: Message constructor must be an array or null" for json_decode($configString, false)"

 and  if I change it to  json_decode($configString, true), error is
"Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Invalid message property: config"

Comment: Just added an answer to your question. Just some recommendations for the future: add additional code to your answer using the "edit" link, code in comments will make it hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

When you `json_decode($configString)`, you receive an object with the properties defined in the JSON. Your JSON object is nothing but a variable holder and it does not contain any functionality. So when you call `->setLanguageCode()` on your config object, it obviously fails.

When I take a look at the [Github repository's RecognitionConfig class](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-speech/blob/master/src/V1p1beta1/RecognitionConfig.php) I see that the class expects to receive an array of properties representing the different settings. The [JSON config sample](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig) also shows that it corresponds to a simple JSON object with Key-Value pairs:

```
{
  "encoding": enum(AudioEncoding),
  "sampleRateHertz": number,
  "audioChannelCount": number,
  "enableSeparateRecognitionPerChannel": boolean,
  "languageCode": string,
  ...
}
```

whereas in your code you wrap the array into an object with the key "config" and an array of settings:

```
{ "config": {
    //encoding is missing since I have an external process converting
    //the files to .wav format
    "sampleRateHertz":8000,
  ...
  }
}
```

Either remove the "config" element (my recommendation as the JSON would be according to the docs again) or change your code to access the config element instead:

```
$config = (new RecognitionConfig($configObj->config));
```

Let me know if this got you further.

Comment: The "config" key is expected. See here: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognitionConfig